# Python: json.load cannot read data from a file

Tags: python, json

I am trying to write a simple code which stores username in json file. If file already exists - additional question (simple verification) will appear.

```
import json

username_file = 'username.json'
try:
    with open(username_file) as file:
        print('Are you ' + json.load(file) + '?')
        check_username = input('Press Y if yes or N if no: ')
        if check_username == 'Y':
            print('Welcome back, ' + json.load(file))
        if check_username == 'N':
            username = input('Input your name: ')
            with open(username_file, 'w') as file:
                json.dump(username, file)
                print('See you next time!')
except FileNotFoundError:
    username = input('Input your name: ')
    with open(username_file, 'w') as file:
        json.dump(username, file)
        print('See you next time!')
```

When I press Y, Python crashes with the following errors:

```
Are you test?
Press Y if yes or N if no: Y
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/medvedev_dd/PycharmProjects/untitled/test.py", line 9, in <module>
    print('Welcome back, ' + json.load(file))
  File "C:\Soft\Python\lib\json\__init__.py", line 296, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
  File "C:\Soft\Python\lib\json\__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Soft\Python\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Soft\Python\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Please explain - why json.load not working when I press Y ? I expect message "Welcome back, test"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the first `json.load` ie,

```
print('Are you ' + json.load(file) + '?')
```

the file pointer is at the end of the `file`. So when you press 'Y'

```
if check_username == 'Y':
      print('Welcome back, ' + json.load(file))
```

there are no more items left to read from its current position(`json.load(file)`).

So you should `seek` to the first position of the file and read it again.

```
if check_username == 'Y':
      file.seek(0)
      print('Welcome back, ' + json.load(file))
```

Comment: Or store the `json.load(file)` content and re-use it.

Comment: Really, when I am adding `username = json.load(file)` and then using `username` - everything works fine. Why I should use separate variable instead of calling `json.load(file)` every time I want?